# Disable send button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to check if a value is selected onh dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("send").click(function () {

if (document.getElementById('dropdown1').selectedIndex == 0)
$("#msg_dropdown1").html("Required");

});
$('#dropdown1').change(function(){$('#msg_dropdown1').hide()})
});
```

Exist a way to disable SUBMIT button until a value is selected?

```
<input type="submit" id="send" value="SEND" class="greyishBtn" />
```

Comment: Isn't `$("send")` wrong?

Comment: Note that if no option is selected, the selected index will be -1 and the test will fail. You should have `.selectedIndex < 1`

Answer (score 0):

change     `$("send").click(function () {`
  to  `$(#"send").click(function () {`

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `ID` selector for `send`

**Repalce** `$("send").click(function () {`

**With** `$("#send").click(function () {`

```
    $('#dropdown1').change(function(){
        if($('#dropdown1').val() != 0){
            $("#send").attr("enabled","enabled");
        } else{
            $("#send").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#send").click(function () {
        if (document.getElementById('dropdown1').selectedIndex == 0)
            $("#msg_dropdown1").html("Required");
    });
    $('#dropdown1').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != 0){
            $("#send").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else{
            $("#send").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });
});

<input type="submit" id="send" value="SEND" class="greyishBtn" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" onchange="unblock(this)">

    function unblock(arg){
      if(arg.options[arg.selectedIndex].value !=0){
      $('#send').css('display','block');
      }
    }
```